# Como é feita o join e WHERE com várias tabelas?

Tags: sql, join, mysql

Eu tenho 4 tabelas eles já estão com foreign key.

```
aluno:
id
matricula
username
curso_id          // referencia a id_cursos da tabela cursos, coluna id_cursos.
```

---

```
cursos: 
id_cursos
nome_cursos
```

---

```
modulos:
id_modulos
nome_modulos
cursos_id         //faz referencia a tabela cursos, coluna id_cursos.
```

---

```
materias:
id_materias
nome_materias
modulos_id       // faz referencia a tabela modulos, coluna id_modulos.
```

---

Como faço o join para retornar as colunas relacionadas destas tabelas ?
se eu executar o código:

```
SELECT cursos.nome_curso, aluno.username 
FROM aluno JOIN cursos on cursos.id_cursos = aluno.curso_id;
```

irá retornar só o relacionamento de destas duas tabelas, mas as 4 estão relacionadas como eu faria isto ?

Comment: Essa foi a melhor pergunta e resposta (do @Bacco) sobre o assunto [**Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441/3635), explica em detalhes cada tipo de JOIN com exemplos, com certeza se você ler vai ver qual se adequá ao seu problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta adicionar os outros relacionamentos no Join

```
SELECT C.nome_curso, A.username, M.nome_modulos, MA.nome_materias FROM aluno A
JOIN cursos C on C.id_cursos = A.curso_id
JOIN modulo M on M.id_modulos = C.id_cursos
JOIN materias MA on MA.id_materias = M.modulos_id
```

aí se você tiver algum relacionamento que necessariamente não precisa estar preenchido, por exemplo, materias, utilize **LEFT JOIN**

Answer (score 1):

Basta você utilizar a mesma lógica que para um JOIN simples, só que utilizando `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

```
Select A.id, A.matricula, A.username, A.curso_id, B.id_cursos, B.nome_cursos, C.id_modulos, C.nome_modulos, C.cursos_id, D.id_materiais, D.nome_materiais, D.modulos_id 
FROM Aluno A LEFT OUTER JOIN Cursos B ON (A.curso_id = B.id_cursos),
LEFT OUTER JOIN Modulos C ON (B.id_cursos = C.cursos_id),
LEFT OUTER JOIN Materias D ON (C.id_modulos = D.modulos_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apenas como acrescento a informação do Thiago Loureiro, ao seleccionares LEFT JOIN
estas a escolher todos os registo que tens a esquerda e apenas aqueles (a direita) que são encontrados. Os restantes (Da esquerda) aparecem na mesma mas sem os dados da tabela da direita.

Se não o fizeres, quando não for encontrada relação o registo da esquerda não e mostrado, sendo "perdido"